# jquery and node.js data is not passing error

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

[image: jquery error]

Could someone please tell me why these errors usually occur, as you could see inside the console the data is present but somehow its not getting passed to the client.This is the syntax inside index.js

```
var li  = jQuery("<li></li>"); 
li.text("${message.from}: ${message.text}");
jQuery("#messagelist").append(li);
```

Comment: Can you place the code that creating this issue? possibly wrong jquery method

Comment: Format and post code and errors not just link and some random part of code.

Comment: Don't use double quotes, they don't work for templating, check  [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for the right symbol to use

Comment: There are no errors. You pass the string `"${message.from}: ${message.text}"` to `li.text()` and so thats what is printed to the screen.

Comment: I tried without the double qoutes, still gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `message` is an object and it's in scope, you can use (before ES6)

```
message.from + ': ' + message.text
```

notice there are no quotes around the expression.

If you are using ES6 then you can use

```
`${message.from}: ${message.text}`
```

Note the use of <kbd>`</kbd> NOT <kbd>"</kbd>. This is called Template literals and is a new feature in ES6 and not all browsers will support it.

You will need to put either of these expressions inside `li.text()`.